# How to skip the expect work and continue process if matched sting found in linux

Tags: linux, shell, expect

I have a process which give the edites like::

CORRECT

INVALID

I have a requirement if a matched string "CORRECT" found then should suspend the expect search and should let continue the process

I am implementing a except script..

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout -1
spawn  "/home/user123/cobltest123.sh"
expect {
"INVALID "    {
                puts "Got $expect_out(0,string)\n"
                exit 4
              }

"Not Coorect" {
                puts "Got $expect_out(0,string)\n"
                exit 4
              }
"CORRECT"    {    }
}
```

If i execute the above script : string "CORRECT" matched and process getting exit.

If i give exp_continue

```
"CORRECT"    { exp_continue  }
```

Then, string matched "CORRECT" and due to `exp_continue`, process is continue to match the string "INVALID" and process ends..

My requirement is string "CORRECT" found then should suspend the expect search and should let continue the process.

Single line : If string "CORRECT" found then script should continue process by suspend of except searching and continue to process.

Please help me to come out from this.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your description. It seems like you only need to take action when Invalid or Not Correct, so why are you matching Correct at all?

Comment: Hi glenn.. Now see my question once again.. i have specified clearly now..

Comment: found solution..`"CORRECT" { expect }` .. this will waits for the furthure pattren...

Answer (score 0):

Ah I see now. This should do what you want:

```
expect {
    "INVALID "    { puts "Got $expect_out(0,string)\n"; exit 4 }
    "Not Coorect" { puts "Got $expect_out(0,string)\n"; exit 4 }
    "CORRECT"
}
# script continues here
```

When expect sees "CORRECT", it will end the `expect` block and continue with your script.